# How to save and load a .txt file with custom name?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, textbox, text-files

I have a popup textbox alert in an app where a user can input characters to create a custom name for a .txt file and then save the file.  This file name is stored in a global variable called rideContent.  When I call the saveRide() function, a file full of string information is stored in a .txt and *should* use file name the user created in the textbox, however the name of the file that is stored within the array is empty.

Am I calling the save function out of order or too soon in the stopAction function and that is why the array is empty?  Or am I calling the rideName = rideContent in the wrong manner? i.e. rideName = rideContent[-1]?

What I would like is for a user to input a custom name, and use it as the identifier to save and load a file.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Here I call a global variable called rideContent:**

```
var rideContent = [String]()
```

**Here I call the save function:**

```
@IBAction func stopAction(sender: UIButton) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Ride Stopped", message: "Give a title to your ride", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .Default,
        handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) -> Void in

            // Allow for text to be added and appended into the RideTableViewController
            let textField = alert.textFields!.first
            rideContent.append(textField!.text!)
            // Update permanent storage after deleting a ride
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(rideContent, forKey: "rideContent")

            // Segue to the Ride details page
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ShowRideDetail", sender: nil)
    })

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel",
        style: .Default) { (action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
    }

    alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler {
        (textField: UITextField) -> Void in
    }

    alert.addAction(saveAction)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)



    //Show the alert
    presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


    // Stop the timer
    timer.invalidate()

    // Stop location updates
    self.stopLocation()

    // Save the ride
    saveRide()
}
```

**Here is the code to save to a text file:**

```
func saveRide() { 
    let rideName = rideContent
    // Print Check
    print("\(rideName) : the name of the saved ride")

    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    let fileName = ("\(documentsDirectory)")+("\(rideName)")+(".txt")
    print("\(fileName)This is firt check")
    var content: String

    // Adding elasped time information to the bicycle ride
    // Content Order: Seconds, Minutes, Hours, Distance \n coordinates
    content = ("\(seconds) Seconds, ")+("\(minutes) Minutes, ")+("\(hours) Hours, ") + ("\(self.distanceLabel.text!)") + "\n"

    // Create a for loop to add each recorded coordinate value to the content list to later be added and displayed as a polyline
    for coord in self.coords {

        content = content + ("\(coord.latitude) " + "," + "\(coord.longitude) " + "\n")

    }
    do{
        try content.writeToFile(fileName, atomically: false, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    }catch _ {

    }
}
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MDK4.png) is a screenshot of where a user can input the custom name. Based on the user input ride name, shouldn't the ride name be called "Morning Ride" in the print check?

This is what prints to the console in my print check statement, *[] : the name of the saved ride*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "saveRide()" function is being called immediately. Put it inside the block so it's called on your saveAction.

Comment: Cheers that worked! It had me call it as self.self.saveRide().  Is it common to call self twice? I have never seen that before...